# AngularJS: unit test page with redirects

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Can you please suggest some good unit test for the following Ctrl?

1. I want to make sure the redirect works correctly
2. Is there anyway I could use Jasmine Spies here / any benefits?
3. Is it possible to test how the controller will behave on forced redirect (redirect to a page with indention of being redirected)?

> ```
> angular.module('app')
>   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'API', '$location', function ($scope, API, $location) {
>
>   // redirect back to login page
>   if( ! API.token ) $location.path('/');
>
>
> }]);
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A unit test should only be concerned about the component that it's testing. You shouldn't need to test what $location actually does but rather that you are calling the method when required. Also you don't care about what the API service does just that when token is falsy the controller calls the location method.

I would:

Mock the service `API`.

Spy the `$location.path` method.

Set `API.token` to `true`.

Check that `$location.path` has not been called.

Set `API.token` to `false`

Check that `$location.path` has been called with the parameter "/".

Something like this:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {

  // Define this test's local variables
  var scope,
      $location,
      MainCtrl;

  // Load the controller's module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  /* jshint camelcase:false */
  // Initialize the controller and scope
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$location_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $location = _$location_;
    spyOn($location, 'path');
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      API: {token: false},
      $location: $location
    });

  }));

  it('should exist', function() {
    expect(MainCtrl).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('when created', function() {

    it('should call $location accordingly', function () {
      expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: There you go. Edited my answer.

Comment: It's important to mention that the `spy` needs to be defined before creating `ctrl`

Comment: This is what I wrote in the meantime http://pastebin.com/iDXZpeVH, any suggestions please?

Comment: Looks good. I don't think you need to test anything else really.